# Method save doesnot exist. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, save

I am trying to insert in image table but following syntax is showing method save does not exit:BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:.

Controller:

```
foreach ($request->file('image') as $i) 
{
    $image = new image();

    $image = $i; 
    $input['imagename'] = $request->vname.'_'.$user->id.'_'.str_random(2).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destinationPath = public_path('/images'); 
     //move image to folder
    $image->move($destinationPath, $input['imagename']);

    $image->title=$input['imagename'];
    $image->filepath=$destinationPath;
    $image->Vehicle_id=$vehicles->id;

    $image->save();

}
```

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Add the full Method please (including paramters)

Comment: **save does not exist:BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74** <-- care to post laravel version and php version?

Comment: I think this line, you assigned the $image = $i;

Comment: https://codeshare.io/a3kjga Full code. @Frank Provost

Comment: Its laravel 5.2 @BagusTesa

Comment: I think i need it to save multiple image. Don't I? @Vineesh

Comment: What does Macroable.php line 74:. contain?

Comment: That's system generated. I have nothing to do with it.

Comment: try $image->move('paht/to/image/image.jpg') instead of save

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the job.

You replaced your model's object with file here `$image = $i;` therefore no save method is availble for `$image`.

```
foreach ($request->file('image') as $file) 
{
    $image = new image();

    $input['imagename'] = $request->vname.'_'.$user->id.'_'.str_random(2).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destinationPath = public_path('/images'); 
     //move image to folder
    $file->move($destinationPath, $input['imagename']);

    $image->title=$input['imagename'];
    $image->filepath=$destinationPath;
    $image->Vehicle_id=$vehicles->id;

    $image->save();

}
```